# How to create tableau columns headers with no column data type using tableau web data connector?

Tags: javascript, php, tableau-api

I am trying to use tableau wdc for the first time using csv file .I also using type file of csv columns. But I dont want to use such type file. I want to use only csv file with tableau wdc.Can tableau know the csv column types with no data type properties?

```
<?php

    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $row = 1;
    $csvdata = $csvtitle = $a = array();
    if (($handle = fopen($id.".csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
           // $num = count($data);
           if($row === 1){
               $csvtitle = $data;
           }else{
               array_push($csvdata,$data);
           }
           $row++;
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    $csvtype = array();
    $row1 = 1;

    if (($handle = fopen($id.".txt", "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $row1++;
            $csvtype = $data;
        }
        fclose($handle);
    } 
?>

(function() {
    var csvtitle = <?php echo json_encode($csvtitle); ?>;
    var csvtype = <?php echo json_encode($csvtype); ?>;
    var csvdata = <?php echo json_encode($csvdata); ?>;

    var myConnector = tableau.makeConnector();
    myConnector.getColumnHeaders = function() {
        tableau.headersCallback(csvtitle, csvtype);
    };
    myConnector.getTableData = function(lastRecordToken) {
        tableau.dataCallback(csvdata, false, false);
    };

    myConnector.init = function() {
        tableau.initCallback();
        if (tableau.phase == tableau.phaseEnum.interactivePhase) {
            tableau.submit();
        }
    };
    tableau.registerConnector(myConnector);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is already a [CSV community provided connector.](https://github.com/starschema/tableau-web-table-connector#csv-connector) . It (internally) tries to guess at the data type just like Tableau.  You could either use that connector or look at their code if it doesn't suite your needs.

Are you just trying to open a local CSV file here?  You could just use the native connector instead and/or upload files directly to Tableau Server with a Creator license (2018.1 and above).

Comment: I am trying to open CSV file from server.

Comment: From Tableau Server?  A file server?  A web server?  Can you give more details?

Comment: Sorry:(
This is my first time asking a question on stackoverflow. 
I am trying to open CSV file from web server.